# Image Uploader using basic oops concepts in php

Tags: php, oop

i am trying to use some basic oops concept for my image uploader but didnt seems to work my basic code what would be the error please help me out of this

```
class allUploader
{
    var $name="sdf";
    var $type="";
    var $error="";
    function imageupload($image)
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
$v=allUploader::imageupload("hello");
echo $v;
```

error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploader in /var/www/imageupload.php on line 20 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/imageupload.php on line 15
```

thanks for your precious time

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? Apparently there is an array, and I'd like to see your calling code. `var` is a php4 throwback, but valid and shouldn't be throwing the fatal error. Also which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: That code by itself doesn't do anything. Where is line 20? Maybe going back to read an OOP introduction would be good?

Comment: @MikePurcell please dont downvote me i have edited my calling code

Comment: Lol, I didn't downvote, just need some more info to better help you.

Comment: @MikePurcell thanks now i have edited my calling code please help me get out this i am new to oops so having problem so started with this basic code

Comment: You can't use $this in a non-instantiated class. 
Here is an example one I wrote that might help you:https://github.com/tehlulz/PHP-Upload

Comment: @tehlulz oh thats so kind of u thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to reference this within in a `static` context, according to your calling code, so you need to do 1 of two things to make it work.

Option 1:

```
// Wrong
$v=allUploader::imageupload("hello");

// Right
$uploader = new allUploader();
$uploader->imageupload('hello');
```

Option 2:

```
// Wrong
var $name = 'sdf';

function imageupload($image)

// Right
protected static $name;

public static function imageupload($image)
{
    return self::$name;
}
```

Option 3

```
// Wrong
function imageupload($image)

// Right
public static function imageupload($image)
{
    $uploader = new allUploader();
    
    return $uploader->name;
}
```

I suggest you give PHP's '[OOP The Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)' a thorough reading, along with [static keywords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).